# boost::sml process_event result

Tags: boost

Attempting to throw exception from guard / action leads to abort. defining noexcept as nothing before including msl.hpp helps.
What is normal way for getting result of call void process_event(event) (i mean handled/unhandled)?

PS: gcc 7.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the document https://boost-experimental.github.io/sml/user_guide.html , if `process_event()` handled the event then returns true, otherwise returns false.

```
template<class T> requires configurable<T>
class sm {
public:
    ...
    template<class TEvent> // no requirements
    bool process_event(const TEvent&)
```

However, the return type of `process_event()` was void in the actual implementation.

So I sent the PR to fix it https://github.com/boost-experimental/sml/pull/303.
And it has been merged.

If you update sml to the current master, then you can know the event is handled/unhandled via the return value.